# How do I define a multiple characters as a single group in python?

Tags: python, string, replace, genetic-algorithm

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import random
import string

chars = ["T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "R1", "R2", "N1",
         "N2", "G1", "G2", "G3", "H1", "H2", "H3", "K1", "K2", "K3", "K4", "D1",
         "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9"]

class Agent:

    def __init__(self, length):
        self.string = ' '.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length))
        self.fitness = -1

    def __str__(self):
        return 'String: ' + str(self.string) + ' Fitness: ' + str(self.fitness)

in_str = None
in_str_len = None
population = 20
generations = 10000

def ga():
    agents = init_agents(population, in_str_len)

    for generation in xrange(generations):
        print 'Generation: ' + str(generation)

        agents = fitness(agents)
        agents = selection(agents)
        agents = crossover(agents)
        agents = mutation(agents)

        if any(agent.fitness >= 100 for agent in agents):
            print 'Threshold met!'
            exit(0)

def init_agents(population, length):
    return [Agent(length) for _ in xrange(population)]

def fitness(agents):
    for agent in agents:
        agent.fitness = fuzz.ratio(agent.string, in_str)
    return agents

def selection(agents):
    agents = sorted(agents, key=lambda agent: agent.fitness, reverse=True)
    print '\n'.join(map(str, agents))
    agents = agents[:int(0.2 * len(agents))]
    return agents

def crossover(agents):
    offspring = []

    for _ in xrange((population - len(agents)) / 2):
        parent1 = random.choice(agents)
        parent2 = random.choice(agents)
        child1 = Agent(in_str_len)
        child2 = Agent(in_str_len)
        split = random.randint(0, in_str_len)
        child1.string = parent1.string[0:split] + parent2.string[split:in_str_len]
        child2.string = parent2.string[0:split] + parent1.string[split:in_str_len]

        offspring.append(child1)
        offspring.append(child2)

    agents.extend(offspring)
    return agents


def mutation(agents):
    for agent in agents:
        for idx, param in enumerate(agent.string):
            if random.uniform(0.0, 1.0) <= 0.1:
                agent.string = agent.string[0:idx] + random.choice(chars) + agent.string[idx+1:in_str_len]
    return agents


if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_str = 'T1T3N1N2H1H2'
    in_str_len = len(in_str)
    ga()
```

In this code, I am using the crossover function and the mutate function to develop stronger populations.
But, I need the those functions to treat the input charachters as one whole unit.
For eg:
While mutating, the function replaces 1 or T from 'T1' or K or 1 from 'K1'
I need it to treat T1 and K1 as a single unit, rather than a string, and replace them as a whole with other units like T2, T3, T4 etc.
Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.
Thanking you.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: If you want that behaviour, you probably shouldn't loop over `agent.string` in `mutation()`: that will loop over the single characters of the string.

Comment: Perhaps better, don't concatenate the individual "genes" at initialization, but save them as a list. Something like `self.string = [random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length)]`. Perhaps rename `string` to `chromosome`, and adjust the rest of your code accordingly.

Comment: Alternatively, take advantage of the fact that all of your genes are two characters long and index `random.choice` accordingly. I agree that saving them as a list is better though

Comment: @Evert Thank you for taking the time to answer me. Would You be able to explain that approach to me a bit in depth, please.

Answer (score 0):

As @Evert and @user3080953 mentioned, the problem lies in your representation of a chromosome.

## What is the goal of your genetic algorithm?

From the code you have provided, it seems that you want the population to evolve towards the given target string `in_str`. But, as you have addressed in your question, some strings are invalid and thus should not be considered (e.g. `T1D8` is a valid chromosome whereas `T18D` is not).

There are a couple of solutions that could potentially remedy this issue:

## Approach #1 (as provided by @user3080953)

Wisely pick your split point during crossover. Since every valid gene is a length `2` string, the split index must be even. So instead of:

```
split = random.randint(0, in_str_len)
```

... you could write:

```
split = 2 * random.randint(0, in_str_len // 2)
```

Then, make similar changes in the `mutation()` function.

## Approach #2 (as provided by @Evert)

Encode each chromosome as a list of strings rather than a single string.

So, change:

```
self.string = ' '.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length))
```

... to:

```
self.string = [random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length)]
```

## Approach #3

This might be overkill, but if you would like some more scalability, you should consider wrapping each gene into an object. For example:

```
class Gene:
    # not literally, but you get the picture hopefully
    Gene._gene_set = set([...])

    def __init__(self, gene_str):
        formatted_gene_str = self._format(gene_str)
        assert self._is_valid_gene_str(formatted_gene_str)

        self._gene_str = formatted_gene_str

    def _is_valid_gene_str(self, gene_str):
        return gene_str in Gene._gene_set

    def _format(self, gene_str):
        return gene_str.strip().upper()    

    def __str__(self):
        return self._gene_str

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(other) is Gene and str(self) == str(other)
```

Also, there seems to be a potential design flaw in your code. You wrote:

```
self.string = ' '.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in xrange(length))
```

... which inserts a space between each gene; however, the target string has no spaces. [`fuzz.ratio()`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuz) uses [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to calculate the differences between sequences.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. You've cleared my doubts.

Comment: about the flaw...can you suggest any other method of string matching which would bypass this issue ?

Comment: @BladeSama If you choose approach #1, just join by the empty string `''.join(...` rather than a space `' '.join(...`. Basically, you just need to make the target object of the same representation of the chromosomes.